# Adding a legend to my plot just floods it with a massive white box

Tags: pgfplots, legend

Normal plot:

[image]

I put `\addlegendentry{Text};` at the end of my `\addplot` and get:

[image]

What's going on?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my black white}{%
solid, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=gray},smooth\\%
}

\begin{axis}[
    align = center, 
    scale only axis,
    separate axis lines,
    xmajorgrids,
    xminorgrids,
    ymajorgrids,
    yminorgrids,
    every outer x axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every x tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    axis background/.style={fill=white},
    legend style={legend cell align=left,align=left,draw=white!15!black},
    every outer y axis line/.append style={white!40!black},
    every y tick label/.append style={font=\color{white!40!black}},
    width=4.396in,
    ymode = log,
    legend pos= north east,
    xmode=log,
     height=4in,
     width=5in,
     ymin = 1,
     ymax = 5e7,
     xmin=1,
     xmax = 1e13,
     cycle list name = my black white,
     legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black},
    xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
    ylabel={$\varepsilon_r$},
]
% beginning of real curve
\addplot  +[shift={(0,1.66)}][solid,smooth] table {
%4e-4 1.5e11
%4e-1 1.5e11
%1e1 1.7e9
%1e4 1e9
%1e7 1e7
%1e10 1e7
0.6935935506675854 6358839.369717595
1.0810961479779755 6256647.653348094
1.6850919101653614 6219151.513328522
2.6265330341021618 6057164.739243777
4.093946293144873 5663765.338770014
6.381186161964233 5242223.3631703835
9.946280170266744 4533376.838573962
15.503150466776145 3613460.8747663563
23.410501447058294 2705296.163166225
33.179087007471686 1930726.0311177357
43.303200469693515 1368798.194095135
55.101160295188194 934331.195776773
77.27249812097367 595088.8109946809
97.4976383399538 406760.2680011097
117.924817640428 284417.3568144273
147.2261143522846 195707.87899043897
195.8400566634882 144651.6411216469
305.2536037494915 116876.09548885858
475.79521875936797 106355.50455252788
741.6164376557404 97773.20362621488
1155.94885975378 93305.42651468949
1801.7639557583987 88739.86443201278
2808.3883857644423 84684.86857952057
4377.402100918816 78916.25822543055
6823.005411309116 74041.89912448576
10634.938662130615 67836.31126934857
16576.55439636832 55371.99222002643
25837.681286702194 42373.008695914345
37008.09739605901 30970.17562424169
50921.3436995039 20085.16587616519
64794.867150672755 13377.23159851167
75924.72044413388 9318.45365575159
94361.73271323873 6426.745687962993
111072.2158870232 4512.824414713201
134343.46745635918 3173.039645838136
157419.72564587265 2201.5676605985154
189541.07397956075 1557.8455158717022
216144.57847833625 1083.2057872842884
274162.6209892914 726.3328977255115
338431.32302362425 480.94783708696286
434161.9675864153 331.4971080757477
577521.8934991601 231.759968525393
900176.6147247838 155.87627983399054
1403094.7515906605 120.91494408514538
2186987.364188686 103.1538602983294
3408831.602925392 91.04224869918396
5313305.914510235 83.12898010055943
8281787.729538139 81.7930298331292
12908725.584540524 78.05547175977598
20120679.454587284 75.76461182683425
31361867.5261861 73.79121319949589
48883375.780125976 71.62550553146538
76193945.5826661 69.99727720062103
118762611.02684627 67.48290960355648
185113891.53107187 63.74634089031428
288534855.7218177 61.66562135853731
449735901.92411715 58.44936157547175
700998085.5640721 53.369022456288974
1092637509.841068 47.102801594100825
1703081295.79416 39.50720010383364
2711275602.2697496 31.273272236283365
3883442575.321119 24.603127999146334
5503900862.033421 18.45786986847493
7321284416.375162 13.272340861499188
9636391769.870033 8.849638582106142
12550242311.245802 5.712012613644441
15668656069.48289 3.8647984115098364
18951468375.282402 2.6388701925863876
22383479213.96965 1.6829904897200278
27030263792.079338 1.1321993592906359
32281521332.049328 0.776804626047292
40559008924.6936 0.5044524664194482
55689398844.76814 0.3433637182140214
86802414059.84824 0.2583316176985687
135297906655.80508 0.21741138124489712
210887263260.00064 0.21031494086779073
810887263260.00064 0.21031494086779073
10010887263260.00064 0.21031494086779073
};
% imaginary peak 1
\addplot +[shift={(4,0)}][densely dashed,smooth] table {
1e-2 1
6e-2 1.3
4e-1 2e3
9e-1 6e3
1.7 2e3 
1e1 1.3 
6e1 1 
};
\node [scale = 1.4]at (axis cs:6e1,7e6) [anchor=south] {$\alpha$};
\node [scale = 1.4]at (axis cs:1.3e5,5e4) [anchor=south] {$\beta$};
\node [scale = 1.4]at (axis cs:0.8e10,0.9e2) [anchor=south] {$\gamma$};
\node [scale = 1.4]at (axis cs:5e1,6.5e3) [anchor=south] {$\varepsilon'$};
% imaginary peak 2
\addplot  +[shift={(-2,0)}][densely dashed,smooth] table {
1e4 1
6e4 1.3
4e5 2e2
8.5e5 6e2
1.7e6 2e2
1e7 1.3 
6e7 1 
};
% imaginary peak 3
\addplot +[shift={(-4.3,0)}][densely dashed,smooth] table {
1e10 1
6e10 1.3
2.5e11 2e1
8e11 4e1
2.7e12 2e1
1e13 1.3 
6e13 1 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*** EDIT ***

A more minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot  +[shift={(0,1.66)}][solid,smooth] table {
0.6935935506675854 6358839.369717595
1.0810961479779755 6256647.653348094
1.6850919101653614 6219151.513328522
274162.6209892914 726.3328977255115
338431.32302362425 480.94783708696286
434161.9675864153 331.4971080757477
3408831.602925392 91.04224869918396
135297906655.80508 0.21741138124489712
210887263260.00064 0.21031494086779073
810887263260.00064 0.21031494086779073
10010887263260.00064 0.21031494086779073
};
\addlegendentry{Text}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile because the package is not `Pgfplots`. Please correct it.

Comment: Even when I correct that, it will not compile. `! Argument of \path has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.221 ...5e1,6.5e3) [anchor=south] $\varepsilon'$}`

Comment: @cfr made the changes for the author

Comment: @cfr It compiles fine for me... but I get the white box? I did take out some data points, which I've no re-added. Hopefully, you can compile?

Comment: @lmsavk It didn't compile for me, either, until I made the changes.  Indeed, there's no way it could compile for you since the code had one more } than it did {'s.

Comment: @JPi does it compile now, with the extra lines? I guess I accidentally half removed some {}s. Do you get the huge legend?

Comment: This is because of `shift={(0,1.66)}`, which is also applied to the legend text. But so far I cannot figure out, what you want to achieve with this. Could you elaborate? Because then we could suggest another solution to that problem.

Comment: @StefanPinnow my post was modified, but the full example has different sections of the plot displayed that are horizontally/vertically aligned with `shift` - because I don't want to edit 50 x coordinates, so I just add an `\addplot` with the coordinates and move that with `shift={(x,y)}`.

Comment: In view of @StefanPinnow's comment this question already appears to have an answer.

Comment: @JPi `+[xshift=1cm,legend image post style={xshift=-1cm}]` doing this for each `\addplot` doesn't work for me

Comment: I imagine you can tell `pgfplots` to calculate a different value for the points it is plotting i.e. tell it to transform each value from the current table by whatever. Then you'd change the plot, rather than shifting it, which I gather is a problematic approach. But if you do use shifts, you'd obviously have to compensate for the `y` as well. What does `doesn't work for me` mean?

Comment: @lmsavk You have to undo the shift that you actually put in there.

Comment: Instead of using `shift` you can use e.g. `\addplot  +[solid,smooth] table [y expr={\thisrowno{1}+1.66}] ...` Of course, in that case, the `1.66` is in axis coordinates, so you might want a different value.